# Use the rules of inference to prove if avb, cvb, d → (¬a ∧ ¬c), d is therefore b

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that the following is valid
avb, cvb, d → (¬a ∧ ¬c), d is therefore b.
Using **ONLY** rules of inference
so far I've gotten,
(1)avb is a premise
(2)cvb is a premise
(3) (avb) ∧ (cvb) from (1),(2) and rule of conjuction
(4) bv(a∧c) from (3) and distributive law
and that is all I've gotten if someone can please help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You have to start from $d$ and use it to derive $¬a \land ¬c$ from 3rd premise

Comment: How do we do that?